# How can i link this to an event on leaflet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, leaflet

I've find a beautiful button in html/css that I have add on my leaflet map. (Adding the lines to my previous code)

I am blocked because this is not a real `<button>` and i don't find anything on Stackoverflow which answer to my question :(

I would like to add any functions which use Javascript, even a simple like add a Pop up when click on the button or anything which related to adding a little bit of interactivity like when click on the button, the zoom go on a specific place of the map.

I just want to know how to link this button to JavaScript.

Find below the section of my code that i want be linked to a function.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:900i');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: right;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.cta {
  right: auto;
  margin-left: 500px;
  top: 520px;
  position: relative;
  left: 500px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 3px 31px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  background: #ffa500;
  transition: 1s;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 0 black;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
}

.cta:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.cta:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 #FBC638;
}

.cta span:nth-child(2) {
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.cta:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-right: 45px;
}

span {
  transform: skewX(15deg)
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 12%;
}


/**************SVG****************/

path.one {
  transition: 0.4s;
  transform: translateX(-60%);
}

path.two {
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: translateX(-30%);
}

.cta:hover path.three {
  animation: color_anim 1s infinite 0.2s;
}

.cta:hover path.one {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  animation: color_anim 1s infinite 0.6s;
}

.cta:hover path.two {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  animation: color_anim 1s infinite 0.4s;
}


/* SVG animations */

@keyframes color_anim {
  0% {
    fill: white;
  }
  50% {
    fill: #FBC638;
  }
  100% {
    fill: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="cta" href="#">
    <span>Datacenter SG</span>
    <span>
          <svg width="66px" height="43px" viewBox="0 0 66 43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <g id="arrow" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
              <path class="one" d="M40.1543933,3.89485454 L43.9763149,0.139296592 C44.1708311,-0.0518420739 44.4826329,-0.0518571125 44.6771675,0.139262789 L65.6916134,20.7848311 C66.0855801,21.1718824 66.0911863,21.8050225 65.704135,22.1989893 C65.7000188,22.2031791 65.6958657,22.2073326 65.6916762,22.2114492 L44.677098,42.8607841 C44.4825957,43.0519059 44.1708242,43.0519358 43.9762853,42.8608513 L40.1545186,39.1069479 C39.9575152,38.9134427 39.9546793,38.5968729 40.1481845,38.3998695 C40.1502893,38.3977268 40.1524132,38.395603 40.1545562,38.3934985 L56.9937789,21.8567812 C57.1908028,21.6632968 57.193672,21.3467273 57.0001876,21.1497035 C56.9980647,21.1475418 56.9959223,21.1453995 56.9937605,21.1432767 L40.1545208,4.60825197 C39.9574869,4.41477773 39.9546013,4.09820839 40.1480756,3.90117456 C40.1501626,3.89904911 40.1522686,3.89694235 40.1543933,3.89485454 Z" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
              <path class="two" d="M20.1543933,3.89485454 L23.9763149,0.139296592 C24.1708311,-0.0518420739 24.4826329,-0.0518571125 24.6771675,0.139262789 L45.6916134,20.7848311 C46.0855801,21.1718824 46.0911863,21.8050225 45.704135,22.1989893 C45.7000188,22.2031791 45.6958657,22.2073326 45.6916762,22.2114492 L24.677098,42.8607841 C24.4825957,43.0519059 24.1708242,43.0519358 23.9762853,42.8608513 L20.1545186,39.1069479 C19.9575152,38.9134427 19.9546793,38.5968729 20.1481845,38.3998695 C20.1502893,38.3977268 20.1524132,38.395603 20.1545562,38.3934985 L36.9937789,21.8567812 C37.1908028,21.6632968 37.193672,21.3467273 37.0001876,21.1497035 C36.9980647,21.1475418 36.9959223,21.1453995 36.9937605,21.1432767 L20.1545208,4.60825197 C19.9574869,4.41477773 19.9546013,4.09820839 20.1480756,3.90117456 C20.1501626,3.89904911 20.1522686,3.89694235 20.1543933,3.89485454 Z" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
              <path class="three" d="M0.154393339,3.89485454 L3.97631488,0.139296592 C4.17083111,-0.0518420739 4.48263286,-0.0518571125 4.67716753,0.139262789 L25.6916134,20.7848311 C26.0855801,21.1718824 26.0911863,21.8050225 25.704135,22.1989893 C25.7000188,22.2031791 25.6958657,22.2073326 25.6916762,22.2114492 L4.67709797,42.8607841 C4.48259567,43.0519059 4.17082418,43.0519358 3.97628526,42.8608513 L0.154518591,39.1069479 C-0.0424848215,38.9134427 -0.0453206733,38.5968729 0.148184538,38.3998695 C0.150289256,38.3977268 0.152413239,38.395603 0.154556228,38.3934985 L16.9937789,21.8567812 C17.1908028,21.6632968 17.193672,21.3467273 17.0001876,21.1497035 C16.9980647,21.1475418 16.9959223,21.1453995 16.9937605,21.1432767 L0.15452076,4.60825197 C-0.0425130651,4.41477773 -0.0453986756,4.09820839 0.148075568,3.90117456 C0.150162624,3.89904911 0.152268631,3.89694235 0.154393339,3.89485454 Z" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
            </g>
          </svg>
        </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Use this: `document.querySelector('.cta').addEventListener('click', function () { ... });` and put your code inside the function.

Comment: Hello Chris thanks for your answer, so if i understand well, i create a .js file, i add the line you give to me, i just add my html between the () , can i delete the code from the html after? :)

Comment: I tried to make a [mcve] from your code but it does nto show anything. Also you do not have to tell us your whole story. If you wish you can fill in your profile

Comment: Hi Paul, no, sorry, that is so far off the mark I suggest doing some basic tutorials first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to display a popup or something on a leaflet map, your posted code should contain your leaflet code. Also it is very helpful when you create a live demo, for example on jsfiddle.

**But now to your question:**

You can add a event over the default way `addEventListener` or with the leaflet library to a element. Here I use it over the leaflet library:

But first add a id to your button `<div class="wrapper" id='testId'>`

```
var button = document.getElementById('testId')
L.DomEvent.on(button,'click',function(e){
    console.log('Button clicked')
});
```

When you want to open a popup on a specific location call:

```
L.DomEvent.on(button,'click',function(){
    var latlng = map.getCenter(); // or [47.478058, 9.720154]
    L.popup().setContent('Test').setLatLng(latlng).openOn(map)
});
```

I think your next question would be *"How can I zoom to a marker"*:

This is a little bit difficult, because we need to know to which marker you want to zoom. This means that you have to save your marker to a global variable, so it can used in the button click event.

```
var latlng = map.getCenter(); // or [47.478058, 9.720154]
var marker = L.marker(latlng).addTo(map);
L.DomEvent.on(button,'click',function(){
    var zoomlvl = 16;
    map.flyTo(marker.getLatLng(),zoomlvl)
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, everything is perfect. I really appreciate the time you take for me! I wish you a really good day, same as mine with your answer!!! Paul